# Problem With Capital Greek Letters

Tags: greek

I am writing an article in the Journal of the Optical Society of America B (JOSA B) and I have used the journal's LaTeX template.

Unfortunately, I have a problem with the output PDF. Instead of capital Greek letters I get a black square and I cannot figure out what the problem is. This problem is exclusively for capital Greek letters. Other letters and mathematical signs are shown properly. I only use the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{osajnl} % http://www.opticsinfobase.org/josab/submit/templates/pc/osajnl_2015.zip (*.zip-file, 581 kB) ‎
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\journal{josab} % Choose journal (ao‎, ‎josaa‎, ‎josab)‎ 
\setboolean{shortarticle}{false} % true = letter‎, ‎false = research article‎ ‎

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
\left[\tilde{V}^{-^{(n)}}\right]=\left[\Gamma^{(n)}\right]\left[\tilde{V}^{+^{(n)}}\right],
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
‎\left[V_m^{(n)}(z) \right]=\left[ P^{(n)} \right]‎
 ‎\left( \left[ \exp \left(‎ -‎j k ^{(n)} \left( z-z_n \right) \right) \right] \left[ \tilde{V}^{+^{(n)}} \right]‎ + \\
 ‎\left[ \exp \left(‎ +‎j k ^{(n)} \left( z-z_{n+1} \right) \right) \right] \left[ \tilde{V}^{-^{(n)}} \right] \right)
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.


Here is an mwe:

‎\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{osajnl}‎
‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath}‎
‎\usepackage{breqn}‎
‎\usepackage{subfigure}‎

‎\journal{josab} % Choose journal (ao‎, ‎josaa‎, ‎josab)‎

‎\setboolean{shortarticle}{false} % true = letter‎, ‎false = research article‎

‎\begin{document}‎

‎\begin{subequations}‎
‎\begin{equation}‎
‎\left[ \tilde{V}^{-^{(n)}} \right] = \left[ \Gamma^{(n)} \right]‎
 ‎\left[ \tilde{V}^{+^{(n)}} \right]‎,‎
‎\end{equation}‎
‎\begin{equation}‎
Eq. 2
‎\end{equation}‎
‎\end{subequations}‎

‎\end{document}‎

Comment: In addition, here is the link of the journal's LaTeX template:

http://www.opticsinfobase.org/josab/submit/templates/pc/osajnl_2015.zip

Comment: In addition, please add the whole comment MWE stuff into your original question above, not as a comment. A comment is limited to about 500 characters and does not really have nice markup, contrary to the question tool above

Comment: unrelated: `subfigure` is obsolete for quite a while. `subfig` is the official successor. `subcaption` is the only package supporting `hyperref` in a satisfying way.

Comment: The culprit is `breqn`. Don't use it.

Comment: @user3276054 Trust me: none of the `\left` and `\right` you're using in the example `align` is necessary.

Comment: @egreg I thought that it might be more professional to use `\left` and `\right`! I used `\bigl` and `\bigr`, and yes, they seem good. Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the call of the `breqn` package.

After the operation I get

[image]

Note that `subfigure` has been obsolete for several years. The official replacement is `subfig`. Alternatively, use `subcaption`. Note that the class already loads `caption`, so `subcaption` should probably be chosen.

I add a version without `\left` and `right`, which don't seem necessary (they rarely are in cases like this) and where the superscripts (n) are similar to the one for Gamma. More importantly, the two consecutive equations are together in a `gather` environment: two `equation` environments should never appear immediately after one another.

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
[ \tilde{V}^{-^{(n)}} ] = [ \Gamma^{(n)} ] [ \tilde{V}^{+^{(n)}} ],
\\
[ \tilde{V}^{-\,(n)} ] = [ \Gamma^{(n)} ] [ \tilde{V}^{+\,(n)} ],
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
```

[image]

In order to accommodate the split formula where you use `\left` and `\right` across lines, just remove all of them; for better clarity, some of the fences can be made `\big`, but not more than that. Note that `multline` is the environment of choice for this.

```
\begin{multline}
[V_m^{(n)}(z)]=[ P^{(n)} ]
 \bigl( \bigl[ \exp \bigl( -j k ^{(n)} ( z-z_n) \bigr) \bigr] [ \tilde{V}^{+^{(n)}}] + \\
\bigl[ \exp \bigl( +j k ^{(n)} ( z-z_{n+1} ) \bigr) \bigr] [ \tilde{V}^{-^{(n)}} ]\bigr)
\end{multline}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But, I must break an equation! I have written this equation instead of Eq. 2 in the MWE above. This equation should be broken between two pairs of `\left(` and `\right)`. I tried the environments `align` and `gather`, but both result in errors. You mean that the best environment for multi-line equations is `gather`?

Comment: @user3276054 You can't split `\left` and `\right` across the various parts of an alignment. Just use `\bigl`, `\bigr` and friends. But, as I showed you, `\left` and `\right` are seldom necessary.

Comment: Does this mean anything? `\tilde{V}^{+^{(n)}}`. Couldn't it be `{\tilde{V}^{+}}^{(n)}` (don't know, just that `+^{..}` seems weird).

Comment: These formulas are for a multilayer structure. + means forward  and - means backward moving waves. (n) shows layer number n.Yes, it can also be like `\tilde{V}^{+\,(n)}` (what egreg mentioned).

Answer (score 7):

@egreg has already identified the source of the main problem: the `breqn` package.

In addition, you may want to make all three `(n)` superscript particles have the same size and vertical displacement (relative to the baseline). Currently, two of the three are in so-called "scriptscript" style while one is in "script" style. All three `(n)` particles should probably be in "script" style and should also feature the same vertical displacement.

I the first row below, I use `_{\mathstrut}` to insert an invisible particle (a "math strut") in the subscript position. This serves to *raise* the `(n)` particles a bit. If that's not what you need, just omit the `_{\mathstrut}` bits -- as is done in the second row below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{osajnl}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\journal{josab} 
\setboolean{shortarticle}{false}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
\left[\tilde{V}^{-}{}_{\mathstrut}^{(n)}\right]=
\left[\Gamma_{\mathstrut}^{(n)}\right]
\left[\tilde{V}^{+}{}_{\mathstrut}^{(n)}\right]\\
\left[\tilde{V}^{-}{}^{(n)}\right]=
\left[\Gamma^{(n)}\right]
\left[\tilde{V}^{+}{}^{(n)}\right]
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```